# Convert from SQL query to Linq Query

Tags: sql-to-linq-conversion

Can somebody please change this query for me to Linq

SELECT Causes.CauseTitle,COUNT(Calender.CauseID) AS NumberOfOccurance FROM Calender
LEFT JOIN Causes
ON Calender.CauseID=Causes.CauseID
GROUP BY CauseTitle;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below linq query. I Did not test this. Let me know if there are any issues.

```
from cal in Calender
join cas in Causes on cal.CauseID equals cas.CauseID into j1
from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group j2 by cas.CauseTitle into grouped
select new { CauseTitle = grouped.Key, NumberOfOccurance = grouped.Count(t=>t.CauseID != null) }
```